# What is the difference between Media and MediaTemplate in WIX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, cab

Is there are manual cabinet file's preparing VS automatic cabinet file's creation during building wix project?

Or may be this is something else ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MediaTemplate replaced Media and is available starting in WiX 3.8.  Take a read at:

[WiX and cabinetry](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2011/06/21/wix-and-cabinetry/)

Basically the Media element took a lot of code to describe what to do when you had more then 1 CAB file.  The MediaTemplate element is syntactical sugar that reduces this to one line.

Many smaller installers with just 1 CAB won't care one way or the other.  But when you start to build large MSIs it'll help.